# Inline Keyboard Callback Button dynamic

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Работаю с Telegram.bot.Api от Mr.Robin
Есть код на составление `Inline Keyboard Callback Button`

```
var keyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
{
    new[] // first row
    {
        new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("1.1", "http://google.com"),
        new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("1.2", "http://google.com"),
    },
    new[] // second row
    {
        new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("2.1", "http://google.com"),
        new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton("2.2", "http://google.com"),
    }
});
```

Подскажите как составить такое же, только динамическое через `for`

Answer (score 0):

Примерно как-то так. Условия в for() придумайте сами.

```
public InlineKeyboardMarkup GenerateButtonsList()
{
    var ikbList = new List<InlineKeyboardButton[]>();
    foreach (......) // rows of buttons
        var ikb = new List<InlineKeyboardButton>();
        foreach (.......)  // buttons
        {
            ikb.Add(new InlineKeyboardCallbackButton(text, url));
        }
        ikbList.Add(ikb.ToArray());
    }   
    return new InlineKeyboardMarkup(ikbList.ToArray());
}
```